# Launch Android application from browser

Tags: android

I have a little problem.

I have an Android Activity, and I want to run it from one link on the browser.

This is what how I have declared my Activity on the Manifest file:

```
<activity android:name=".Wul4"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="wul4" android:host="com.wul4.wul4"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

On the webApp, the link to launch the application is the following one:

```
wul4://com.wul4.wul4?codOperacion="+respuestaActual.idOperacion
```

The point is that It is working from the following browsers: "Opera" and "Google Chrome", but it is not working for the rest..........(for instance, it is not working on the default browser of the phone).

Anyone knows why???

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, using HTTP instead of your own schema:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

  <data
    android:host="com.wul4.wul4"
    android:scheme="http:" />
</intent-filter>
```

When a link with this domain is clicked in an Android device, the user is presented with a dialog to choose between your App (if installed) or the Browser.

Comment: Yes, that could be a solution, but i don't want my application to be launched everytime u click on a link with an "http", that's why i created my own scheme, to be launched just from the web application I have. Anyway, I think that's the only solution, cause with my own scheme. I was just wondering if I was doing something wrong, but I guess that's just not possible. Thank u anyway!

Comment: I don't know if I understood you correctly, but the activity will be offered to be launched just for the webpages containing "com.wul4.wul4", not for every http link. Anyway, you can add another attribute called android:pathPattern to launch the activity only on those links in your website following a specific pattern. Own schemas are not recommended.