# Launch Instagram application from Firefox on Android

Tags: android, html, mobile, instagram

I'm building an HTML5 application that will be accessed via Firefox on an specific Android tablet. One of the main options is to share an image on Instagram.

For Apple devices we have the "instagram://" hooks, but they don't exist for Android. I've already read a lot about to use Intent, but I think it's not possible since it's an web app.

I need any solution to get out of my Firefox browser and show Instagram application. It's okay to minimize the browser and just go to the main Android screen.

Someone have any idea?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849307/launch-android-application-from-browser

Comment: I think it won't work, cause I'm trying to launch a third-party application, like Instagram.

Answer (score 1):

[If i understand your question I think this is what your are looking for](https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/intents)

**EDIT: taken from that site as an example**

> To launch the Zxing barcode scanner app, you encode your href on the
>   anchor as follows:
>
> `<a href="intent://scan/#Intent;scheme=zxing;package=com.google.zxing.client.android;end">`
>
> Take a QR code  See the [Android Zxing Manifest](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android/AndroidManifest.xml#97), which defines the
>   package and the host.

Comment: I tried to implement what you pointed me, but my link opens the market application instead of Instagram. Any idea? Here is the code:<a href="intent://instagr/#Intent;scheme=instagram;package=com.instagram.android;action=android.intent.action.MAIN;category=android.intent.category.LAUNCHER;end;">Link</a>

Comment: on my phone ATM.  First, it doesnt look like the main activity is browsable.  So it wont work and is missing fields.  The view activity is.  so the next thing I notice is your host is wrong.  it should be either instagr.am or instagram.com not instagr.   Next, your scheme should be http or https, not instagram.  your package looks good.    Finally I don't think you need the category.   Idk if it hurts anything or not.

Comment: https://raw.github.com/danthemellowman/instagram-decompiled/master/AndroidManifest.xml

the manifest I was using.

Comment: @pedrorezende_ did you ever find a solution for this? I'm in a similar situation ... can't even get your pasted code above to open the market application.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying it. Unfortunately I didn't find any solution so far :/ . Thanks for all the answers @8bitwide, but I didn't get that. Maybe I skipped something on the way. I'll try to hack it again soon, I'll let you know if I get any advance on this stuff.

Comment: Instagram has some documentation on using intents to launch a share window http://instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/android-intents/.   I haven't been able to create a working link, but thought I would share.